# FileUtils.mv([fileutils], [apache-fileutils]) ; FileUtils.mkdir([fileutils])

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki, tag-disambiguation

The tag wiki for [fileutils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fileutils) says

> FileUtils is a File manipulation utility from Apache Commons
>
> `FileUtils` or `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` is File manipulation
>   utility from [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)

However, it's being used in other contexts, such as in [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby), where it is the name of a module.

Either the tag wiki needs updating, or it needs splitting into [apache-fileutils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-fileutils) for Apache Commons and [fileutils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fileutils) for the general concept in Ruby and other programming languages.

As background information, there's currently 4 questions tagged [gnu-fileutils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-fileutils).